# Does windows 10 installed in mac hardware using bootcamp causes error with using oracle database?

Tags: database, oracle

I am currently learning to program with Java.
Now I am learning how to use Oracle database with oracle 11g XE.

So far, I have installed latest windows 10, tomcat 8.5, eclipse neon, jdk1.8.
I have installed windows 10 on my macbook pro using bootcamp assistance.

This is the code I tried on SQL commandLine
[image]

wasn't very successful so i tried this next
[image]

I have other solutions on the internet but none of them worked.
So i was wandering if windows 10 installed in mac hardware using bootcamp causes problem with oracle database.

Comment: Why do you think this is specific to MacBook hardware? The error in the first image is just telling you the database is down. The second is telling you why. See MOS note 1575865.1 for what that means - seems to be related to bug 14518031. But ultimately looks like you have a corrupt block on your disk, which seems to be a disk error and not something specific to Oracle. (Also, [please post text rather than screenshots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/266304).)

Comment: thanks for the reply. yes i do think that there are no problems with oracle. service running normally, but I just can't get to it. I asked this question because I also had this exact problem while using macbook. however on my non-apple laptop it works fine. (oh yes i will remember to post code as a text rather than screenshots)

Comment: The Windows service may be running (no idea how independent that is); but the database itself isn't running, and can't be started. I imagine the service  is trying and failing to start the database too. If you have a pfile copy of your spfile, or a backup of your spfile you can restore elsewhere, you could try to start from that instead. I'd start by running a disk check though, it may even be able to fix the block or recover the existing file itself.

Comment: Hmmmm I dont understand what you are saying. But I do appreciate you advice and possible solution. Thank you Alex. So far i had no luck on solving this problem.

Comment: Not really on-topic for this site, but... run First Aid or Verify Disk from the Mac OS Disk Utility (depends which version; I think I might have read it doesn't exist in Sierra?). Then from Windows, from a command prompt, run `chkdsk /b` to queue a full disk check with bad-block detection, and reboot Windows. See what it reports, and see if Oracle will start afterwards.

Comment: found out the reason...finally...there is nothing work with the apple hard, but there was a problem with windows that was installed with bootcamp assistance. I re installed windows with bootable USB. and it works just find. Alex Poole thank you. and I believe this post will get deleted soon according to stack overflow.

Comment: I still think, from the error message, that's a block error on your hard disk - possibly one MacOS is aware of and avoiding, but Windows hasn't noticed yet. I'd still do a disk check and see if it reports anything. There may be others, and they might cause other problems later.

Comment: It also happening to me. I'm suspecting it is due to hardware problem.